# I am travelling to Austria for 6 months, is there any travel/health insurance I could get if I have a European (Spanish) passport?

Tags: health, insurance, austria, spanish-citizens

I'm a 25 year old Uruguayan who will be living in Austria for 3 to 6 months. I have a European passport/nationality (Spanish).

I am in the process of getting health/travel insurance here, but all the insurance companies, have really economical plans up to 3 months, and then go completely nuts after that period.

I wanted to exhaust all other possibilities; is there any kind of insurance I could pay for that would cover medical costs in case of an incident?

I'm not sure if it is relevant but: I'm a student here in Uruguay, and I have family members living in Austria.

Comment: So you have a Uruguayan and a Spanish passport?

Comment: @RoflcoptrException Yes, I am Uruguay, living in Uruguay, but I have a Spanish passport too for blood heritage. I'm both a Uruguayan and Spanish citizen.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException I just checked, my Spanish passport says Born in Uruguay but the nationality states Spanish.

Comment: Do you qualify for a Spanish [EHIC](http://ec.europa.eu/social/main.jsp?catId=89&langId=en&newsId=1039&furtherNews=yes)? Or have you not spent enough time there to get one?

Comment: @Gagravarr I never lived in Spain, I will call the embassy tomorrow to see if I qualify and report back! Thanks!!

Comment: An important factor will be your status in Austria. What are you planning to do there?

Answer (score 1):

Try [World Nomads](http://www.worldnomads.com/).  I plugged in your information and the quote came out to be ~400 Euros for 6 months for a Spanish resident.  A Uruguayan resident would pay slightly more.  3 months would cost ~230 Euros.  I use World Nomads every time I travel, but I've never had to make a claim.  From the research I've done, mostly the Thorn Tree forum on Lonely Planet's website, they're pretty good at paying out claims.

Comment: Lots of bad reviews of World Nomads here: http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g293974-i368-k5446738-o10-World_Nomads_travel_insurance-Istanbul.html